# Is there any "extra regularity" to the solution to Poisson's equation posed on a 3-dimensional polyhedron?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

I am trying to write a proof and I am out of my depth.  I need an elliptic regularity result of the form 
$$
\|u\|_{H^{1+\epsilon}(\Omega)} \le C \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$

for some $\epsilon >0 $ where $u$ is the weak solution to either of the following PDEs.

\begin{align*}
\nabla\cdot\nabla u &= f\quad x\in \Omega\\
u &= u_D\quad x \in \partial \Omega_D\\
\nabla u\cdot n& = 0\quad x\in \partial\Omega_N 
\end{align*}

or the pure Nuemann problem with the further restriction that $\int_\Omega f \mathrm{d}x = 0$,
\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot \nabla u &= f\quad x\in \Omega,\\
  \nabla u \cdot n &= 0 \quad x\in \partial\Omega,\\
  \int_\Omega u\, \mathrm{d}x &= 0.
\end{align*}

This result is known for the case of two dimensional polygons (I am interested in 3-dimensional polyhedra), and the largest $\epsilon$ depends on the measure of the interior angles.

I have looked into a few promising papers with ["Analytic Regularity for Linear Elliptic Systems in Polygons and 
Polyhedra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.1772.pdf)" being among them. I suspect that Theorem 1.4, in that paper (which references theorem 2 in  [On the Agmon-Miranda Maximum Principle for Solutions of Elliptic Equations in Polyhedral and Polygonal Domains](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226589031_On_the_Agmon-Miranda_Maximum_Principle_for_Solutions_of_Elliptic_Equations_in_Polyhedral_and_Polygonal_Domains)), implies what I need, but, like I said, I am out of my depth here and quickly get bogged down, and completely lost.

Comment: [Maz'ya and Rossman's _Elliptic equations in polyhedral domains_](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-162) seems promising, and may be more digestible than the original papers.

Comment: Maybe [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X99965186) could also be useful.

Comment: @Hannes Your suggestion was exactly what I needed.  I wouldn't have found it without you.  What I asked for is pretty much exactly theorem 1 in that paper.  If you want to write an answer to this I will accept your answer.  Thank You!

Comment: @Hannes Are you familiar with the paper?  Do you know if there is any reason why Theorem 1 couldn't be extended to the pure Nuemann case?

Comment: I think the pure Neumann case is excluded (although I couldn't find the precise point where it explicitly is) because the differential operator is not coercive on the Sobolev space if there is not a small Dirichlet part of the boundary: the operator lacks the classical "$+1$" or "$+u$", or the space lacks a condition which exludes constant functions other than the constant zero function, such as the mean over $\Omega$ as you posed it. I would expect this to be a more or less straightforward modification, though. If this is still helpful to you, I'll happily post the answer of course.

Comment: @Hannes, I am working on understanding the proof to understand if I can extend it to the pure Neumann case.  I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @fred We are in fact working on a generalization of the results in the paper to even more nonsmooth settings by abstract interpolation principles. In case of pure Neumann boundary, there will not be an improvement, though; but if you are interested, feel free to send me an eMail (I will update my profile.. ;)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, such a result can be found in [Jochmann's "An $H^s$-Regularity Result for the Gradient of Solutions to Elliptic Equations with Mixed Boundary Conditions"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X99965186).